# Deleting files from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, synchronization, delete

I want to remove files from Google Drive, but I don't want them deleted from my hard drive. when I delete something from Google Drive it tells me that it will also be removed from my computer. I don't want that.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this. The cloud is supposed to be somewhere to keep your files safe from a computer that crashes. Extra storage does not cost much.

Comment: Nowadays there are two sync apps. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In case it's important for you to synchronize the account with a local directory on your computer,

And you just do not want the files you deleted from the cloud to be deleted from the local directory on your computer.

**You can do this:**

> 1. On your computer, click Backup and Sync [image]
> 2. Click More [image] [image] **Preferences**.
> 3. Next to "Removing items," click the Down arrow Down [image]:
>
>    - **Ask me before removing items everywhere:** When you delete something on your computer, it will ask if you want to delete it everywhere.
> 4. Click **OK**.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987

Comment: Wouldn't a better answer be to change that setting to "Don't remove items everywhere"?

Answer (score -2):

- disable synchronization between your computer and Google Drive 
  (or directly uninstall Backup and Sync)
- go to **https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive**
- delete everything you wish